# Redstone XML RPC ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser

Tags: java, xml-rpc

The below exception I was facing some times  .

```
Caused by: com.comviva.ngage.ocs.redstone.XmlRpcException: null
        at com.comviva.ngage.ocs.redstone.XmlRpcParser.parse(XmlRpcParser.java:127) ~[commonutils-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at com.comviva.ngage.ocs.redstone.XmlRpcClient.parse(XmlRpcClient.java:539) ~[commonutils-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:230) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:191) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at com.comviva.ngage.ocs.redstone.XmlRpcParser.parse(XmlRpcParser.java:123) ~[commonutils-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance.newInstance(NewInstance.java:82) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:228) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        ... 88 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Post adding the  below maven dependency , the error has not seen . And my application working fine now .

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
            <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```